# How to restore the original Backtrack Taskbar

Tags: gui, desktop-environment, backtrack

I accidentally removed the my taskbar on Backtrack 5 and am having trouble returning it. If I minimize anything it gets lost and I can't access it again.

How do I go about restoring it?

Answer (score 1):

The taskbar should be the gnome-panel, if you lost it, just right click on the top one, and Add a new Panel, and add the corresponding items to the newly created panel (it would be at the bottom automatically).

The items are "Show Desktop", "Windows list", "Trash"

or if you mean the wbar, try install it again, first find the package name with `apt-cache search wbar`, then do a `apt-get install XX` to install it.

Comment: Thanx, it worked... Ijust needed to add "Windows list" to the new Panel.